# How do I stop getting reminders form a deleted Exchange account?

Tags: calendar, exchange

I have an HTC Desire phone which is great apart from the incessant recurring meeting calendar reminders from my former company. I have deleted the Exchange account and these recurring meetings no longer show up in my regular calendar, but the reminders keep coming!

How do I clear out these reminders?

Comment: +1 - I searched a number of sites and found requests for a solution to this going back to August.  There was not a single response on how to resolve this.

Comment: Assuming the reminders are coming from the Calendar app, have you cleared the data for it?

Answer (score 1):

Try clearing your calendar data (Settings -> Applications -> Calendar -> Clear Data).

If that doesn't work then you might have to resort to a factory reset.

(If you have to go this route then there are lots of options for backing up your data before hand to minimize the pain)